# How to split XML tag with PHP Function?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I'm importing a XML tag into WordPress

```
<inspection>21-Oct-2018 10:30AM to 10:50AM</inspection>
```

I need to seperate the date and time into two seperate fields with PHP

So

```
Field 1 = 21 Oct 2018
Field 2 = 10:30am to 10:50am
```

I know this is a very broad question but does anyone know how to achieve this in PHP?

Comment: How are you receiving the XML? Just as a string, or in some XML DOM library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Receiving the XML as a String @Dai

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Start by parsing XML using an XML parser. That leaves you with a string which you could simply `explode` on its first space to mostly end up with the desired result. Where exactly are you stuck in this process?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an elegant solution but it works, if the inspection date never truly deviates from how it is displayed.

```
$str = "<inspection>21-Oct-2018 10:30AM to 10:50AM</inspection>";
preg_match('/(\d+\-[A-Za-z]+\-\d{4})\s(.+\s.+\M)/',$str,$temp);
echo $temp[1]."\n";
echo $temp[2]."\n";
```

Outputs

```
21-Oct-2018
10:30AM to 10:50AM
```

Use https://regex101.com/ for explanation of Regular Expression as I could not do it justice with my explanation.

Hope this helps.

as function:

```
function sep_times($str){
    preg_match('/(\d+\-[A-Za-z]+\-\d{4})\s(.+\s.+\M)/',$str,$temp);
    return $temp;
}
```

Use:

```
$variable = sep_times($your_xml_string); //"<inspection>21-Oct-2018 10:30AM to 10:50AM</inspection>"

echo $variable[0]; //outputs 21-Oct-2018 10:30AM to 10:50AM
echo $variable[1]; //outputs 21-Oct-2018
echo $variable[2]; //outputs 10:30AM to 10:50AM
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Will give this one a try and let you know how I go

Comment: @Paul D you are welcome I updated the answer for you. :)

Comment: @himspeil thank you I will give it a try and see how we go